# style binding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, knockout.js

Have you any idea, why the following code isn't working?
I have two ajax calls to get data from Server i wan to displayin my master file. I want the UI to bind to the values i get from the calls. The data i get back is correct, but color is always yellow and red, as if alarms and warnings would be true, even if they are false. Also the attr-Binding never sets the databadge attribute to false, but if alarmCount or messageCount is > 0, it is displaying the correct value.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <%-- header large --%>
<header id="header_large_container" class="hide-for-medium-down large-10">
    <div class="row main_header text-right" id="header_large">
        <i class="fi-alert size-21 badge1" data-bind="attr: { databadge: warnings ? warningCount : false }, style: { color: warnings ? 'yellow' : 'white' }"></i>
        <i class="fi-x-circle size-21 badge1" data-bind="attr: { databadge: alarms ? alarmCount : false }, style: { color: alarms ? 'red' : 'white'}"></i>
</div>
</header>

 <%-- header small, medium --%>
<header id="header_small_container" class="hide-for-large-up fixed">
<div class="row main_header">
    <div class="columns small-2">
      <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle" href="#"><i class="fi-list"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns" style="padding-top: 15px">
              </div>
        <i class="fi-alert size-21 badge1" data-bind="attr: { databadge: warnings ? warningCount : false }, style: { color: warnings ? 'yellow' : 'white'}"></i>
        <i class="fi-x-circle size-21 badge1" data-bind="attr: { databadge: alarms ? alarmCount : false }, style: { color: alarms ? 'red' : 'white'}"></i>

</div>
</header>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var myViewModel = {
            alarmCount: ko.observable(0),
            alarms: ko.observable(false),
            warningCount: ko.observable(0),
            warnings: ko.observable(false),
        };

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).foundation();

            ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('header_large_container'));
            ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('header_small_container'));

        })

 $.ajax({
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetAlarmCount",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                myViewModel.alarmCount(data.d);
                if (data.d > 0) {
                    myViewModel.alarms(true);
                }
                else {
                    myViewModel.alarms(false);
                }
                return false;
            },
            error: function (xhr, statusText, error) {
                alert("Error on Default.aspx/GetAlarms: " + xhr.responseText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetWarningCount",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                myViewModel.warningCount(data.d);
                if (data.d > 0) {
                    myViewModel.warnings(true);
                }
                else {
                    myViewModel.warnings(false);
                }
                return false;
            },
            error: function (xhr, statusText, error) {
                alert("Error on Default.aspx/GetAlarms: " + xhr.responseText);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why did you edit the heading? Sorry, it is my first time asking a question here!

Comment: What's a "databadge" attribute? Is that meant to be the same as jQuery Mobile "data-badge"?

Comment: It is only an attribute definded be myself, i use it for css.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just missing some `()` to unwrap (read) your observable properties in your if/else logic:

Instead of:

```
databadge: warnings ? warningCount : false
```

use:

```
databadge: warnings() ? warningCount() : false
```

If you use observable values on their own in a binding (`data-bind="{text: someObservable}"`) then knockout silently unwraps the value of `someObservable` for you. You could use `data-bind="{text: someObservable()}"`, but you don't have to.

However, if you use a calculated expression knockout can no longer do this for you and you have to unwrap all values yourself: `data-bind="{text: someObservable() + '!'}"`.